# Unable to tag users in reply to comments

Tags: support, comments, notifications

For this question here, [How can international students with weak work experience overcome logistical difficulties in seeking work in the United States?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49493/how-can-international-students-with-weak-work-experience-overcome-logistical-dif) , I am unable to tag users as I want to reply to the user who posted the second answer with a clarification.

Typing the @ symbol and the first few letters of his name, does not trigger the autocompletion request. Manually typing his name after the @ symbol does not work either as after I hit save, the @symbol followed by the user name disappears. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The owner of the post is automatically notified of all comments on it, so the system "helpfully" removes your "@author-name" text as redundant.  This trips up lots of people; you are not alone.  The author will get your message, so go ahead and comment.

See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for more information.